# SQL Update Statement for Queries with no ID Take ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the table below.

I need to update every line that has no second_id (second_id=0).

But only every line where Status is 0 and second_id is 0 and then i have to use the last second_id value from the last line of Record with second_id and take this second_id as id and put it auto_increments to all the records where second_id = 0 and status is 0.

In the table below only the Record with id 5 will be updated and the second_id 6 (last second_id 5 + 1).

Is that possible only with an SQL Statment ?

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| id   | second_id  | y       | z       | status |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|    1 |        3   |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    2 |        4   |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    3 |        5   |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    4 |        0   |    jaaa | 3       |   1    |
|    5 |        0   |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    6 |        0   |   aaaaa | 2       |   0    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Result after Update:

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| id   | second_id  | y       | z       | status |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|    1 |        3   |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    2 |        4   |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    3 |        5   |      ja | 1       |   0    |
|    4 |        0   |    jaaa | 3       |   1    |
|    5 |        6   |     jaa | 2       |   0    |
|    6 |        7   |   aaaaa | 2       |   0    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I use a MySQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL will do what you are asking:

MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @I INT = (SELECT TOP 1 SECOND_ID FROM TESTTABLE ORDER BY SECOND_ID DESC)

UPDATE TESTTABLE
SET SECOND_ID = @I, @I = @I + 1
WHERE SECOND_ID = 0 AND STATUS = 0
```

MySQL:

```
SET @I := (SELECT second_id FROM MyTable ORDER BY second_id DESC LIMIT 1);

UPDATE MyTable 
SET second_id = @I := @I + 1
WHERE second_id = 0 AND status = 0;
```

For a single line solution, create a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE RunIncrement()
BEGIN
DECLARE I = (SELECT second_id FROM MyTable ORDER BY second_id DESC LIMIT 1);
UPDATE MyTable 
SET second_id = I := I + 1
WHERE second_id = 0 AND status = 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then call the procedure when needed.

```
CALL RunIncrement();
```

Comment: How can i put it in one Statement ? I think these are two Statements or ?

Comment: @wp-developer I answered this before you had stated this was MySQL. I'm working on the MySQL version now.

Comment: @wp-developer I updated my answer to include MySQL. I believe that is the correct syntax, but I cannot currently test it.

Comment: I can take a look at this later tonight. When this was originally posted, there was no mention of MySQL or PHP.

Comment: Sorry my mistake :-( i had an error in the second query thats why in doesnt work :-( now it works ;-). Cool.

Comment: Great to hear! If the answer was helpful, please consider marking the answer as correct.